# Is there a reason stackoverflow converted my affiliate links?

Tags: support

[UX for full stack developers](https://ux.stackexchange.com/questions/60247/ux-for-full-stack-developers/60249#60249)

I contributed to the stack overflow site by offering book recommendations. I used amazon affiliate links, and was surprised to see there's 0 clicks. On the web page, it's being re-rendered to direct through stack overflow.

Is stack overflow getting money from my affiliate links? If so they are basically stealing money away from me for my time and effort, and giving no indication that they're doing so, which would be dishonest.

Comment: Posting links to someone else's website for the purpose of making money off those links is pretty spammy.

Comment: According to the ToS and the licence, both of which you agreed to be using the website, SE and any user have the right to change the content you posted, however they want. This happened.

Answer (score 14):

Posting affiliate links on someone else's web site is kind of scammy, in my opinion. You're not paying the bills here, Stack Exchange is. They have the right to delete them or change them to their own affiliate account so that they can offset the cost of hosting content. This was [suggested in 2008](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10948/1288) and [implemented in 2009](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2009/11/our-amazon-advertising-experiment/).

Also, the question you answered is off-topic. One of the reasons we don't like questions that ask for recommendations is that they attract spam, which is not much different from what you posted.

Comment: It's not off-topic, it's poorly moderated. The article was put on 'hold' because the answers wouldn't include "facts, references, or specific expertise" when my answer referenced three books. I hope someone doesn't put this question on hold because you answered with an opinion. The fact is it's stealing, according to my lawyer. I emailed stackexchange, asking for my money back.

Comment: @TylerLangan I'd like to know where you got the idea that doing it in the first place would be okay.

Comment: @TylerLangan In fact, unless I'm reading the wrong agreement, [you aren't allowed to do that on site you don't own.](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/agreement?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_i=assoc_operating_linking&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_167729822_1)

Comment: "Scammy" is putting it politely.

Answer (score 3):

As pointed out by Daedalus [in the comments](https://ux.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1646/is-there-a-reason-stackoverflow-converted-my-affiliate-links#comment3932_1647):

> ...unless I'm reading the wrong agreement, [you aren't allowed to do that on site you don't own.](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/agreement?ie=UTF8&pf_rd_i=assoc_operating_linking&pf_rd_m=ATVPDKIKX0DER&pf_rd_p=&pf_rd_r=&pf_rd_s=assoc-center-1&pf_rd_t=501&ref_=amb_link_167729822_1)

Here are some of the relevant parts of [Amazon.com's Associates Program Operating Agreement](https://affiliate-program.amazon.com/gp/associates/agreement) that support that (additional bold emphasis mine):

> **“Your site”** means any site(s) and software application(s) that **you own or operate** and link to the Amazon Site.
>
> #### Description of the Program
>
> The purpose of the Program is to permit you to **advertise Products on your site** and to earn advertising fees for Qualifying Purchases (defined in Section 7) made by your end users.
>
> #### Links on Your Site
>
> After you have been notified that you have been accepted into the Program, **you may display Special Links on your site.**

and it goes on like that several more times throughout the contract.

**I am not a lawyer**, but since it's most certainly the case that **none of the Stack Exchange sites are "your sites"**, there's a very good chance that you may have violated your Amazon contract by essentially spamming your affiliate links on someone else's site, in which case Amazon might very well terminate your agreement.